# Symfony v3.4 "Command 'command_name' is not defined"

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.4

when running a Symfony (v3.4) command, receive an error that "Command 'command name' is not defined."
there is no ->setHiddent(true) in its configure() method. also, when listing the Symfony commands thru 'php console list' command, it is not getting listed. where else (or thru what other options/settings) could it be hidden or disabled?

Comment: Could you please share the code of your command